# How to run pmd through pom without failing the build in Jenkins?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pmd

I am running pmd (checkstyle and findbugs as well) via maven plugins in my pom.xml. The build on Jenkins fails due to errors reported by pmd.

The build stage runs 6 modules in parallel and I run the publisher and another stage after that. If pmd fails the whole build fails and stops immediately.

This is a snippet from my pom.xml:

```
</properties>
    <failOnChecks>true</failOnChecks>
</properties>
<!-- ...... -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd-core</artifactId>
            <version>${version.pmd}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd-java</artifactId>
            <version>${version.pmd}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd-javascript</artifactId>
            <version>${version.pmd}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${version.pmd}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.software</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${version.build-tools}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <rulesets>
            <ruleset>pmd/ruleset.xml</ruleset>
        </rulesets>
        <failOnViolation>${failOnChecks}</failOnViolation>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The Jenkinsfile has those two stages:

```
stage('modules') {
  gitlabCommitStatus('modules') {
    parallel Config.stepsForParallel
  }
}

stage('Jenkins Code Analysis') {
  pmd canRunOnFailed: true, canComputeNew: false, defaultEncoding: '', healthy: '', pattern: '', unHealthy: ''
  checkstyle canRunOnFailed: true, canComputeNew: false, defaultEncoding: '', healthy: '', pattern: '', unHealthy: ''
  //findbugs canComputeNew: false, defaultEncoding: '', excludePattern: '', healthy: '', includePattern: '', pattern: '', unHealthy: ''
}
```

It fails in the build before the second stage can be reached.

The plugins should not stop the pipeline but instead finish it and then fail, and run the publisher afterwards, so I can see the issue in Jenkins.

So far I set *failOnViolation* via a property, but I am not able to let the build fail at the end. I think I need to check the status there somewhere and call error.

Is there any cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: First why have you defined dependencies to the plugin? Furthermore have you checked to call Maven via: `mvn --fail-at-end ...`?

Comment: 1: This was done by a colleague. I guess he had his reasons to do that. I could probably remove them.

2: --fail-at-end probably won't work since every build runs an own mvn command.  --fail-never is probably not that good either because it may suppress any other failures as well.

Comment: Adding those dependencies to the plugin does not really make sense, cause the plugin already has those dependencies...Are you using a CI solution to run those builds? If yes you can change the configuration of the maven call.

Comment: We use Jenkins. The problem is not to configure the maven calls but the order they are called. The build stage calls the build function which in turn runs every module one by one. If I add -fae there it will still stop the pipeline before the "Jenkins Code Analysis" stage will be reached, right?

Comment: `-fae` will not stop the pipeline. If you build has issues than the pipeline will be stopped. If you need to continue in such cases you need to cache the error in the pipeline...

Comment: The dependencies make sense when you want to run the latest version of PMD. The maven-pmd-plugin is usually several PMD versions behind as it gets updated less often than PMD itself. As of right now maven-pmd-plugin uses PMD 5.6.1 while the latest version of PMD is 5.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the goal `pmd` instead of `check` which will analyse the code and generate a report but will not fail the build. Then configure Jenkin's [PMD Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/PMD+Plugin) and [Static Code Analysis Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/analysis-core) to mark the build as failed or unstable depending on the number of violations in the report.

Note that changing the goal will also stop failing the Maven build when run manually. We usually configure the maven-pmd-plugin in `<pluginManagement>` without the `<executions>` and create two Maven profiles: a default profile that runs maven-pmd-plugin with the goal `check` and a profile `jenkins` with the goal `pmd`. By doing it this way a developer can run the build manually and it will fail when there are PMD violations while it will not fail when run on Jenkins with the profile `jenkins`.